# Como alterar o rótulo padrão "Selecionar aquivo" do input file?

Tags: html

Estou elaborando um formulário com um campo `<input type="file">`. Como faço para alterar o rotulo padrão 'Selecionar arquivo'?

Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de alterar este rótulo padrão por um personalizado.

Comment: De uma olhada nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button)

Answer (score 1):

Até onde sei, não é possível edita-lo, mas tem algumas alternativas exemplo...

Substituir pela `label`.

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
.btnPerson {
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<label for="teste" class="btnPerson">Escolha um arquivo</label>
<input type="file" id="teste">
```

Porém o resultado do nome da imagem só poderá ser feito através de javascript.

Outra alternativa é usar um pronto, já usei esse aqui [Input file tutorialzine](https://demo.tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/), e recomendo.